# NameError: a global name 'RPyPException' is not defined

Tags: python, r, rpy2

2ND question:
Thanks so much Ben! It works! I got at Error 13 message saying I couldn't make a temporary file in C:\Program Files so I movd the ARSER folder and put it under my user name. That took care of the Error 13 but now I get NameError: a global name 'RPyPException' is not defined. Is this because I moved the folder out of the Program Files folder where I have saved R, Python, and rpy? Thanks!

---

1ST question:
I am trying to analyze biorythm data with a program called ARSER (http://bioinformatics.cau.edu.cn/ARSER/) and when I try to run it I get the error:

File "C:\Program Files\ARSER\arser.py", line 9, in  from rpy import * Import Error: no module named rpy

I am running WINDOWS 7 and have downloaded:

1. Python(x,y) running Python version 2.7.2.3
2. windows patch for Python 2.7 (pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe)
3. R version 2.8.1
4. rpy version 2.2.3

Under the My Computer Advanced Options I changed the environmental variable PATH to C:\Program Files\R\R-2.8.1\bin but this did not solve the above error. The help instructions I was reading were from an older version of R so maybe that's the problem?

I am new to all these programs and I appreciate any suggestions you have! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to change the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the directory containing `rpy`. Python knows where to search for modules when you import something by using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, much as the shell knows where to look for a program that you type the name of by using the `PATH` environment variable.